# Keeping metadata in FFmpeg image sequence to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, quicktime, exif

When creating a video from an image sequence with FFmpeg, how do I also copy the metadata from the first image in the image sequence (within reason: creation date, GPS coordinates, etc.; maybe not rotation, for example) into the output video.

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_%04d.jpg -vcodec libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -preset fast -crf 20 -an -vf "format=yuv420p" -r 30 out.mov
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/how-to-prevent-ffmpeg-from-dropping-metadata

Comment: No. The answers to that question have no effect when the input is an image sequence. Adding `-movflags use_metadata_tags -map_metadata 0` (or viceversa) after the input file sequence pattern accomplished nothing: ffprobe still returns no metadata that would have come from the first image's EXIF, and the same with exiftool, which for instance reports a CreateDate of the output of `0000:00:00 00:00:00` whereas the first input image did have a proper EXIF date.

Comment: Images use different metadata than videos, thus it probably doesn't work